# Node.js: alternative to setInterval which is more precise for game loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer, game-loop

My setup is a multiplayer game, with sockets to async transfer data.

Now because of the nature of a game, I have a game loop which should tick every 500ms to do player updating (e.g. position, appearance,...).

```
var self = this;

this.gameLoop = setInterval(function()
{   
    for (var i = 0; i < playerSize; i++)
    {
        self.players.get(i).update();
    };
}, 500);
```

I'm currently using `setInterval` but when i did some benchmarks with about 200 connections, `setInterval` drifted away to 1000ms instead of 500ms, which makes the whole game appear laggy. Also it's not accurate enough unfortunately with a little amount of players. (note that the update calls only take about 100ms maximum)

So to me after researching, there seems to be no other option then to spawn a process which only handles the timining mechanism? Or are there other options?

Anyone has done this before or can give some fundamental ideas/solutions on how to do this?

Full code:

```
Game.prototype.start = function()
{
    var average = 0;
    var cycles = 10;
    var prev = Date.now();

    this.thread = setInterval(function()
    {       
        console.log("interval time="+(Date.now() - prev));
        prev = Date.now();

        var s = Date.now();

        // EXECUTE UPDATES
    for (var i = 0; i < playerSize; i++)
    {
        self.players.get(i).update();
    };

        average += (Date.now() - s);

        cycles--;
        if(cycles == 0)
        {
            console.log("average update time: " + (average/10) + "ms");
            average = 0;
                cycles = 10;
            }
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: You said `update()` only takes about 100ms. How did you benchmark this? And does it mean the whole loop with 200 players only takes 100ms or one single call of `update` takes 100ms?

Comment: Hi, all the updates of the players takes less than 100ms, my point was just to make note that it is not more than the interval time. I measured it with a Date.now() difference

Comment: Can you maybe show, in code, how you measured it? I am not sure, but considering these huge differences (from 500ms to 1000ms), I would assume, that the benchmark is maybe incorrect and that your loop actually takes more time then 500ms to execute which make the intervals become longer and possible overlapping.

Comment: I've updated my post.

Comment: Ok, looks good. Could it maybe have something to do with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927284/how-can-i-make-setinterval-also-work-when-a-tab-is-inactive-in-chrome/7387953#7387953

Comment: I don't think so, this is not in a browser.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an article on creating an [accurate node.js game loop](http://timetocode.tumblr.com/post/71512510386/an-accurate-nodejs-game-loop-inbetween-settimeout) using a combination of `setTimeout()` and [`setImmediate`](https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_setimmediate_callback_arg) so things are accurate but don't use up too much CPU.

The [nanoTimer timing library](https://github.com/Krb686/nanotimer) might work for you. From the readme it sounds like it uses a similar approach. I don't know if it's been designed with games in mind but it should be worth a try!

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't work with games, there is a better alternative than setInterval, as shown [here](http://www.thecodeship.com/web-development/alternative-to-javascript-evil-setinterval/). It worked well for me in a business application. I hope this helps.